# Python-Docx no reemplaza texto en tablas

Tags: python, docx

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python y estoy haciendo un función simple con Tkinter para ingresar datos y que se reemplacen en un .docx, venía funcionando todo con normalidad hasta que comencé a trabajar con tablas, ahí fue cuando ya no supe como seguir, reemplaza el texto correctamente, no reemplaza en las tablas, alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

```
def docx_find_replace_text(doc, search_text, replace_text):
    paragraphs = list(doc.paragraphs)
    for t in doc.tables:
        for row in t.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    paragraphs.append(paragraph)
    for p in paragraphs:
        if search_text in p.text:
            inline = p.runs
            started = False
            search_index = 0
            found_runs = list()
            found_all = False
            replace_done = False
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if search_text in inline[i].text and not started:
                    found_runs.append((i, inline[i].text.find(search_text), len(search_text)))
                    text = inline[i].text.replace(search_text, str(replace_text))
                    inline[i].text = text
                    replace_done = True
                    found_all = True
                    break
```

Comment: Hola Ectomorfus, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Para reemplazar texto en las tablas de un archivo de Word usando la librería python-docx, debes recorrer las celdas de la tabla y buscar el texto que deseas reemplazar. Luego, puedes usar el método `cell.text = 'nuevo texto'` para reemplazar el texto.

Por ejemplo:

```
def docx_find_replace_text(doc, search_text, replace_text):
    paragraphs = list(doc.paragraphs)
    for t in doc.tables:
        for row in t.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    paragraphs.append(paragraph)
                    if search_text in paragraph.text:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            if search_text in run.text:
                                new_text = run.text.replace(search_text, replace_text)
                                run.text = new_text
                        cell.text = cell.text.replace(search_text, replace_text)
    for p in paragraphs:
        if search_text in p.text:
            for run in p.runs:
                if search_text in run.text:
                    new_text = run.text.replace(search_text, replace_text)
                    run.text = new_text
                else:
                    continue
    doc.save('file.docx')
```

En este ejemplo, se recorren todas las celdas de todas las tablas del documento, y se busca el texto que se desea reemplazar. Si se encuentra en alguna celda, se reemplaza el texto usando el método `cell.text = 'nuevo texto'`. Además, se continúa buscando en los párrafos de las celdas para asegurarse de reemplazar todo el texto. Finalmente, se guarda el archivo. Saludos!